# What is an example of an endergonic reaction?

Tags: biochemistry

I am doing a project where I must find both an endergonic and exergonic reaction. The latter seems to be abundant, but the endergonic reactions seem to be purely biological. I have to present the reaction. The only thing I can think of that is endergonic (that isn't biological) is ice melting. Is there some kind of chemical reaction that's endergonic that anyone knows about? I have access to laboratory chemicals if I need to use them. If all else fails, I can do ice melting, but that sure will be pretty boring.

Thanks!

Comment: If you take an exergonic (spontaneous) reaction, the reverse reaction is endergonic (nonspontaneous). Ice melting is not good enough. Below the freezing point, ice melting is endergonic, but above freezing, it is exergonic.

Comment: You can look examples by yourself. Type on google any reactions and analize Gibbs Free energy (if they occur at constant T and P as in the body). Here you have a very good link http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch21/gibbs.php. Good luck!